# problem with constructor parameter in rawtransaction

Tags: solidity, web3js, constructor

I am using remix and ganache to test out my contract. The contract deploys successfully, however, I do not see the state variables initialized with the constructor parameters when I look at the deployed contract in remix... will appreciate any feedback on what is wrong with the following setup

```
    let rawTx = {
        from: runENV.acctAddr,
        nonce: runENV.web3.toHex(runENV.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(runENV.acctAddr)),
        gasLimit:30000000,
        //gasPrice: runENV.web3.toHex(20000000000),
        data: runENV.bin,
        arguments: ["param1", ["one", "two", "three"]],
    }

    let transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(runENV.privateKeyBuffer);

    let serialzedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');

    runENV.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction( '0x' + serialzedTx, (err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(`Error in deploying new record on bchain - ${err}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`record contract deployed successfully ${res}`);        
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done similar work , what i found different was --> you have to pass data in you contract constructor as shown below :-

```
var data = require('../contractABI/data');
var contract_abi = abiData.abi;
var demo_Contract = web3.eth.contract(contract_abi);
//getting public keys 
var owner_add = <address of owner , you can use your address like sender/rec addr>;
var deployer_add = <address of deployer , you can use your address >;

let deploy = demo_Contract.new.getData(
    contract_data.tokenURI,
    owner_add,
    parseInt(contract_data.shares),
    contract_data.companyName,
    parseInt(contract_data.priceShares),
    {
        data: data.abiData,
    });
let gas = web3.toHex(contract_data.gas_limit)
let gasPrice = web3.toHex(contract_data.gas_price)
let nonce = web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(deployer_add))
let transactionObject = {
    gas: gas,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    data: deploy,
    from: deployer_add,
    nonce: nonce
};
//getting private key of admin
var private_key = privateKeyService.getPrivateKey(contract_data.depemail).slice(2);
var txData = new Buffer(private_key, 'hex');
var transaction = new tx(transactionObject);
transaction.sign(txData);
var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, function (err, txHash) {
    if (txHash) {
        txnStatus(txHash, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err, null);
            } else {
                next(null, result);
            }
        })
    }
    else if (err && err.message) {
        next(err.message, null);
    }
    else {
        next('Unable to sendRawTransaction', null);
    }
});
```

As i have created a deploy identifier and by using demo_contract(var demo_Contract = web3.eth.contract(contract_abi);) , you have to call getData method and pass arguments in you contract constructor.

In my case i have 5 arguments in my contract constructor which are :-

```
contract_data.tokenURI,

owner_add,

parseInt(contract_data.shares),

contract_data.companyName,

parseInt(contract_data.priceShares),
```

similarly you have to pass you arguments to constructor of your contract and then you have to pass this identifier in data of transaction object as shown in code.